# Trying to model nested sum objective function with 14 constraints in gurobi

Tags: python, gurobi

I am trying to model a nested sum objective function in Python using gurobi where I maximize the double sum x(i,j) for i=0 to 19 and j=0 to 19 where x(i,j) are binary variables and subject to 14 constraints listed below:

1. x(0,13)+x(0,4)+x(0,17) <= 1
2. x(4,0)+x(4, 18)+x(4,17) + x(4,12)+x(4,11)+x(4,9)+x(4,7)+x(4,6)<=1
   ...
   and so on.

I can define 40 variables as binary variables using the following command:

```
from gurobipy import *
m = Model()
x1 = m.addVar(vtype=GRB.BINARY,name="x013")
```

But I am struggling to define the z function here: `m.setObjective(z , GRB.MAXIMIZE)`

Could you please help with the structure of what the code should look like? I am very new to Gurobi.

I am expecting to see maximum matches. So the function should output the chosen variables since the constraints only allow for one variable connection to be chosen as they are bidirectional nodes meaning if x(0,4) is chosen, then x(4,0) cannot be chosen. Other than that, I am struggling to figure out how to write the code for this.

Answer (score 0):

Does below code snippet help. Essentially, you will create e dimensional decision variable, indexed by  `i` and `j`. Gurobi will create a `tupledict` object, on which you can call `sum` function to add all the terms.

```
import gurobipy as gp
from gurobipy import GRB

m = gp.Model()

i = range(20)
j = range(20)

x = m.addVars(i, j, vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS)

m.setObjective(x.sum(), GRB.MAXIMIZE)
```

Answer (score 0):

#define variables

```
x={}
z= m.addVar(vtype=GRB.INTEGER)
for i in range(20):
   for j in range(20):
      x[i,j]=m.addVar(vtype=GRB.BINARY, name = f"x_{i}_{j}")
```

#Constraints

```
m.addConstr(x[0,13] + x[0,4] + x[0,17] <= 1)
m.addConstr(x[4,0] + x[4,18] + x[4,17] + x[4,12]+x[4,11]+x[4,9] + x[4,7]+x[4,6]<= 1)
for i in range(20):
   for j in [t for t in range(20) if t!=i]:
       m.addConstr(x[i,j] + x[j,i] <= 1)
m.addConstr(z-quicksum(x[i,j] for i in range(20) for j in range(20))==0)
```

#objective

```
m.setObjective(z, GRB.MAXIMIZE)
```